# How is Joda MutableDateTime's setDate(DateTime) method working?

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a test:

```
@Test
public void testJodaStartDate2a() {

    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2010,10,10,4,0, DateTimeZone.forID("America/Caracas"));

    MutableDateTime mutableDateTime = dateTime.toMutableDateTime();
    mutableDateTime.setDate(dateTime);
    assertEquals(dateTime, mutableDateTime.toDateTime());
}
```

It's straightforward, and in it I want to set the date part of dateTime value to the date part of dateTime value, which should be valid, and the assertion should succeed. However it fails.

As I can't debug the methods of Joda, I created another test, which emulates what setDate() must do:

```
@Test
public void testJodaStartDate() {

    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2010,10,10,4,0, DateTimeZone.forID("America/Caracas"));

    long instantMillis = DateTimeUtils.getInstantMillis(dateTime);
    Chronology instantChrono = DateTimeUtils.getInstantChronology(dateTime);
    DateTimeZone zone1 = instantChrono.getZone();
    if (zone1 != null) {
        instantMillis = zone1.getMillisKeepLocal(DateTimeZone.UTC, instantMillis);
    }

    MutableDateTime mutableDateTime = dateTime.toMutableDateTime();
    mutableDateTime.setMillis(mutableDateTime.getChronology().millisOfDay().set(instantMillis,
                                                                                mutableDateTime.getMillisOfDay()));
    assertEquals(dateTime, mutableDateTime);
}
```

This test is a copy of setDate()'s contents. As I have seen during debugging, at first, after

```
long instantMillis = DateTimeUtils.getInstantMillis(dateTime);
```

the instantMillis variables is assigned a value of 1286699400000 which is 2010-10-10 04:00 (VET) and 2010-10-10 08:30 (UTC).

After

```
instantMillis = zone1.getMillisKeepLocal(DateTimeZone.UTC, instantMillis);
```

the instantMillis is 1286683200000, which is  2010-10-10 00:00 (VET) and 2010-10-10 04:00 (UTC).

At assertion, the milliseconds value of mutableDateTime is 1286613000000 which is 2010-10-**09** 04:00 (VET) and 2010-10-**09** 08:30 (UTC)..

Isn't this function just supposed to recalculate the date part of mutableDateTime to the date part of parameter value? What am I missing in the tests? I am very much appreciated.

Comment: And? This is the code from the second test, as I took it from Joda's source. As far as I understand, it sets the date part not from the instant I pass into it, but from the instant, which represents the same local time but in UTC timezone. And that's why it fails, because the instant in UTC is another date in VET in this case (-1 day in the date part). When it invokes setDate(long), it looks up the date part of long by first converting it to the hosting mutableDateTime value. And it is 1 day back. So that's why it doesn't work. Correct?

Comment: You asked how the method works, and said you couldn't debug the methods of joda (I don't know why you couldn't). So I just told you where you could find the sources to see how it works.

Comment: Thank you, but I've got the sources, and as I can't debug them I created the second test, where I have inlined this method to.

Comment: I missed that. Sorry. But there's really no reason why you couldn't debug joda's code. Just attach the sources to joda's jar file in your IDE.

Comment: And the first test is just telling it's not working as it's intuitively implied to work imho, so I got surprised and asked this question so someone could either confirm and deny I am missing nothing, and that, yes, this is just the way it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have discovered a bug.

The following line is wrong -- it should use the time zone that `this` is using.

```
instantMillis = zone1.getMillisKeepLocal(DateTimeZone.UTC, instantMillis);
```

A quick search hasn't found a current bug. I've filed one now ([here](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3572478&group_id=97367&atid=617889)).

Some tests I ran to check which time zones were problematic for this time. Basically it seems that the problem occurs when the date at given time zone is different to the date at UTC (at the same instant).

```
@Test
public void minus0401() {
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime("2010-10-10T04:00:00",
            DateTimeZone.forOffsetHoursMinutes(-4, 1));
    testDate(dateTime);
}

@Test
public void testIds() {
    List<String> failedIds = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String id : DateTimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime("2010-10-10T04:00:00",
                DateTimeZone.forID(id));
        try {
            testDate(dateTime);
        } catch (AssertionError e) {
            failedIds.add(id);
        }
    }
    assertEquals(failedIds.toString(), 0, failedIds.size());
}

@Test
public void testHours() {
    List<Integer> failedHours = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = -12; i < 12; i++) {
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime("2010-10-10T04:00:00",
                DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(i));
        try {
            testDate(dateTime);
        } catch (AssertionError e) {
            failedHours.add(i);
        }
    }
    assertEquals(failedHours.toString(), 0, failedHours.size());
}

private void testDate(DateTime dateTime) {
    MutableDateTime mutableDateTime = dateTime.toMutableDateTime();
    mutableDateTime.setDate(dateTime);
    assertEquals(dateTime, mutableDateTime.toDateTime());
}
```

Comment: Fixed in https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/commit/cd24d5cb2a981ed5af3a3060399a13e010c33a6f